# Can't run h2o.init() on server CentOS 7

Tags: r, h2o

I m using h2o package from R on a server with CentOs 7.

I installed correctly library. Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Settled correctly as JAVA_HOME.
When I run `h2o.init()` I got this long message with error

```
rary: xgboost4j_gpu
11-22 10:42:12.375 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost supported backends: [WITH_GPU, WITH_OMP]
11-22 10:42:12.375 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-wright
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Build git hash: 0457fda98594a72aca24d06e8c3622d45bd545d2
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-rel-latest-stable-1-g0457fda
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Build project version: 3.20.0.8
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Build age: 2 months
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Built on: '2018-09-21 16:54:12'
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git branch: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.376 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git hash: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Watchdog Build git describe: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Watchdog Build project version: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Watchdog Built by: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Watchdog Built on: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost Build git branch: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost Build git hash: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost Build git describe: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.377 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost Build project version: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost Built by: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: XGBoost Built on: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git branch: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git hash: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build git describe: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Build project version: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built by: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: KrbStandalone Built on: (unknown)
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Processed H2O arguments: [-name, H2O_started_from_R_datascience_msi886, -ip, localhost, -web_ip, localhost, -port, 54321, -ice_root, /tmp/RtmpooR6rF]
11-22 10:42:12.378 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 4
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 121.0 MB
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 1.73 GB
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0_181 (from Oracle Corporation)
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-Dsys.ai.h2o.debug.allowJavaVersions=11, -ea]
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: OS version: Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 (amd64)
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 7.80 GB
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1542879731843
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: User name: 'datascience'
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: IPv6 stack selected: false
11-22 10:42:12.379 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: ens160 (ens160), fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:feb4:1f23%ens160
11-22 10:42:12.380 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: ens160 (ens160), 10.0.1.110
11-22 10:42:12.380 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
11-22 10:42:12.380 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
11-22 10:42:12.380 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      FATAL: On localhost/127.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port PORT and try again.
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] FALSE
[1] 503
[1] ""
```

I looked at the log and this is what's displayed

```
11-22 10:42:12.380 127.0.0.1:54321       31865  main      FATAL: On localhost/12                                                                                                                                                             7.0.0.1 some of the required ports 54321, 54322 are not available, change -port                                                                                                                                                              PORT and try again.
```

But it's quite weird since before running all this I verified that the specified port were available. I'm quite desperate, hope you can help.

Thanks

**update**

So I managed to run. I went under

```
/home/datascience/.checkpoint/2018-11-20/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/3.5.1/h2o/java
```

and run `java -jar h2o.jar` and I found instance running under port 54323.
Then i come back to R and run

```
 h2o.init(ip='machine_ip',port=54321,max_mem_size='2g',startH2O=FALSE)
```

and it worked. But why?? I shutdown everything , reopen it and the only to make things work is to run `java -jar h2o.jar` and then go to R session and run `h2o.init()`

Comment: did you try  changing the default port?

Comment: see updated post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution with a software engineer working in my company.

He simply wrote a bash which will call "java -jar h2o.jar" that manually start h2o cluster and inside R script I connect to the existing h2o instance through

```
h2o.init(ip="machine_ip",port=number_port,startH2O=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

h2o.init() will look for an existing h2o instance.  since you started one by hand with “java -jar h2o.jar” h2o.init() found it and connected to it.

if you don’t specify an IP address, and h2o.init() does not find an h2o instance already running, then h2o.init() will try to make one if startH2O is true.  the message saying that port 54321 or port 54322 is not available means exactly that.  one of them must have been taken even if it’s not what you intended.  Use “netstat -anp” to diagnose port usage on linux.

Comment: I assure you that first thing I did was to check which ports were available, even before running "java -jar h2o.jar"